# how to button linked to a new page

Tags: button, hyperlink, addition

I am using CodeIgnighter framework. In my view I want to change the page when I click the button.

[image]

I set the `base_url` correctly.

Comment: why not use href?

Comment: Did my answer help???

Comment: please paste actual code instead of screenshots. Then people can use it in their answers easily. You'll find it's actually faster and easier to copy/paste rather than upload an image!

Comment: @Tomm Thanks for answering to solve me the problem. when using codeIgnither li we have to provide url from base url . before provide url we have to set the base url in config/config.php file as "http://localhost/(File name in www)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="imports/add_user" class="button">Insert</a>
<a href="imports/modify_user" class="button">Modify</a>
```

You can also do it like this :

```
<form action="imports/add_user">
    <input type="submit" value="Insert">
</form>

<form action="imports/modify_user">
    <input type="submit" value="Modify">
</form>
```